# Who got the highest gold, silver badges in Drupal Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer

I have searched who got the highest badges in Drupal Stack Exchange.

Got this url it shows a query screen for stack overflow site.

http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/268877/top-100-users-with-most-gold-badges

```
select top 100 b.userid, u.displayname, count(*) as gold
from badges b
inner join users u on u.id = b.userid
where name in ('Socratic', 'Stellar Question', 'Great Question', 'Famous Question', 'Illuminator', 'Great Answer', 'Populist', 'Reversal', 'Unsung Hero', 'Fanatic', 'Legendary', 'Marshal', 'Constable', 'Sheriff', 'Steward', 'Copy Editor', 'Electorate', 'Publicist')
group by b.userid, u.displayname
order by gold desc
```

Is there any link for Drupal stack exchange site!

Comment: Just run the same query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/drupal/query/new

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace *stackoverflow* in that link with *drupal*, and you are set: http://data.stackexchange.com/drupal/query/268877/top-100-users-with-most-gold-badges.